# Finding difference between two dates using mktime()

Tags: c, postgresql, unix, time, mktime

I am trying to find the difference between two dates in seconds.

I have used tm1 and tm2 to store the two different dates.

```
tm1 = 1900-01-01 00:00:00
tm2 = 2000-01-01 20:38:40
```

```
tm1.tm_year = 0  
tm1.tm_mon  = 0  
tm1.tm_mday = 1
```

```
tm2.tm_year = 100  
tm2.tm_mon  = 0  
tm2.tm_mday = 1  
tm2.tm_hour = 20  
tm2.tm_min  = 38  
tm2.tm_sec  = 40
```

Now to the code :

```
time_t t1, t2;
t1=mktime(&tm1);
t2=mktime(&tm2);
int diff = difftime(t2,t1);
```

The actual value of `t1` in this case is `2209010000` and that of `t2` is `946739320`.

Now I executed a similar function using PostgreSQL :

```
select EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ('2000-01-01 20:38:40' - CAST('1900-01-01' AS TIMESTAMP)));
```

But the result from `difftime()` **function** is `3155749320` and the result through **querying** is `3155747920`, a difference of 1400 seconds.

Why is there a difference in the result obtained from both the methods? What would have caused the difference? Do I need to handle time zones?

Comment: (1) What values are in `tm1` and `tm1`?  (2) Are you working with 32-bit or 64-bit C? (3) What answer do you get from PostgreSQL?  (4) What answer did you get from your code?  (5) What values do you get in `t1` and `t2`? You've missed every single important detail.

Comment: What does `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM …interval_expression…)` do in PostgreSQL?

Comment: `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM …interval_expression…)` provides the number of seconds within the specified interval.

Comment: You say `tm1` is `1900-01-01 00:00:00`; what is the value in `tm_year`?  What is the value in `tm_mon`? Similar comments apply to `tm2`.  Don't hide information when something is going wrong!  People can't help you if you don't show what you are doing.  We don't know where you're running into trouble — we only know that you are running into trouble.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and post one!

Comment: If it's any help, Informix gives the same answer as PostgreSQL — 3155747920. I would need to see how you've initialized your data structures. The value 1400 seconds corresponds to 23m 20s; there isn't an obvious source for a gap like that because of time zones, not that it was all that likely that time zones were a factor. The 3155747920 corresponds to 36524 days 20:38:40. Your calculated value, therefore, corresponds to 36524 days 21:02:00. You must be using a 64-bit system; 32-bit time runs into trouble on or before Friday 13th December 1901. The 3 billion and change seconds shows that too.

Comment: tm1.tm_year=0, tm1.tm_mon=0, tm1.tm_mday=1 and tm2.tm_year=100, tm2.tm_mon=0, tm2.tm_mday=1, tm2.tm_hour=20, tm2.tm_min=38, tm2.tm_sec=40 @jonathan leffler

Comment: Yes, i am using a 64-bit system. But why is there a difference of 1400 seconds? How can i correct this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130920/discussion-between-rrr-and-jonathan-leffler).

Comment: Did you forget to explicitly set hour, minute, and second of `tm1` to `0`?

Comment: No i have set hour, minute and second to zero already @KlasLindbäck

Comment: I can't help further.   You have not shown an MCVE as requested.  It is extremely worrying that you show values being set for date fields and not time fields for `tm1`.  However, without an MCVE, there is no point in further discussion.

Comment: @RRR " i have set hour, minute and second to zero already" is insufficient.  `struct tm` has _at least_ 9 fields.  All but 2 of them need to be set prior to `mktime()`.  Set _all_ fields to 0, then assign select ones.  `struct tm tm2 = {0 }; tm2.tm_year = 100; ...`, also `tm1`.

Comment: Curious that code is having trouble with conversion, yet `t1=mktime(&tm1);` is not followed by a check for validity.  `if (t1 == -1) Error();`.  Eliminate easy problems by _coding_ with error checking.

Comment: "The actual value of `t1` in this case is 2209010000" is an unreproducible fiction.  Post _code_ the shows this value occurred.  Likely OP's unposted code did not properly initialize/assign `tm1`

Comment: Well, the actual Unix timestamp for jan/1/1900 is `-2208988800`, and not the quantity you have shown.  For your information the `0` second in unix time is 1/1/1970, so your value cannot be positive.  You are doing something weird with your timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

The unix timestamp for a given date begins at 1/1/1970, so the first thing that hits me when you show your timestamps is that 1/1/1900 should be negative.  If we analize the exact UNIX timestamp for the date you used, it should be `-2208988800` (for `1/1/1900 00:00:00 UTC`) which is larger (in absolute value) than the lowest minimum integer representable in 32 bits (in two's complement) which is `-2147483648`.

If you want to do exact calculations, you have to switch to 64bit integers, and you'll get the correct result.

- Unix timestamp for `2000-01-01 20:38:40 -> 946759120`
- Unix timestamp for `1900-01-01 00:00:00 -> -2208988800`
- difference between the two: `946759120 - (-2208988800) = 3155747920 s.`

The timestamp you obtained are the 32 least signifiant bits of the overflown result.  The minimum date possible with 32 bit timestamps in two's complement is for `-2147483648 -> 13/Dec/1901, 20:45:52`.